# Calculating the Coordinates of a Regular Polygon Given Its Center and its side length

Tags: math, geometry

I was wondering how to calculate the coordinates of a regular polygon given its center and its side length. I came up with a method for the square already, but I am looking for something that could be applicable to other regular polygons.

Comment: So do you want a square, or other regular polygons as well?  Are these oriented in some way, or can they be spun arbitrarily?  What do you mean by "the coordinates of a square" anyway?

Comment: `x = centerX - (side / 2)`, `y = centerY - (side / 2)`, developing a more general formula for other regular polygons would require more parameters

Comment: Which part pf the square determines the coords?

Comment: Did you have a particular orientation in mind, or any arbitrary rotation will do?

Comment: What do you mean "coordinates of a square", do you mean coordinates of its corners?  Center and side length are not enough to determine the coordinates of the corners.  Is the square oriented with edges parallel to the axes, or is it rotated?  Perhaps you think the answer is "obviously parallel to the axes," but this doesn't make any sense once you start talking about any other type of polygon.

Comment: Center coordinate and side length are insufficient on their own.  You also need to know the angle the sides make relative to their cartesian coordinate system.  There's a potential rotation required to transform from square coordinates to global coordinates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question is poor formulated. But let's assume that the most right edge of regular polygon is vertical. N is number of edges, L is side length. All vertices lie at circle with center given (CX, CY). Radius of this circle:

```
R = L / (2 * Sin(Pi / N))
```

I'th vertice of regular N-gon has coordinates:

```
i = 0..N-1
X[i] = CX + R * Cos(Pi/N * (1 + 2 * i))
Y[i] = CY + R * Sin(Pi/N * (1 + 2 * i))
```